# Sitecore 8.2 GeoIP Service

Tags: geolocation, sitecore8

I am using Sitecore GeoIp service to get the user country. When I am loading the page first time it is returing country = "N/A". But when I reload the page, it returns the correct country.

I am using following code to get the country.

var ipAddress = x.x.x.x;

var geoIpOptions = new GeoIpOptions
     {

Ip = ipAddress,

```
     MillisecondsTimeout = 1000,

     Id = GeoIpManager.IpHashProvider.ComputeGuid(ipaddress)

  };
```

var geoIpResult = GeoIpManager.GetGeoIpData(geoIpOptions);

string country = geoIpResult.GeoIpData.Country;

Please let me know if I am missing something to get the correct country on first load itself.

Thanks,
Alok...

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore does not wait until the information has been obtained from the GeoIP service in case the response takes a long time. In order to force it to wait on the first request, you can install one of the packages mentioned in this kb article: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/320734

I have tested this in a production implementation and it works well.